# How to start a Genius Scan intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

Is it posssible to start genius scan (or something similar, as long as its free) as an intent to get its picture?
Or make it appear in the 'open with' dialog?
I have already tried contacting the manufacturer and googled the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2021-04-30**

> Starting in Android 11, only pre-installed system camera apps can respond to `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE`

**Update 2020-07-03**

It's now possible to start Genius Scan with an intent, either `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE` or `com.thegrizzlylabs.geniusscan.DOCUMENT_CAPTURE`.

See this help article for more details:
https://help.thegrizzlylabs.com/article/182-open-genius-scan-from-another-app

**Old answer**

Being the developer of Genius Scan, I can tell you that there is currently no way to do this. Genius Scan does not have any intent filter. Users can only export scans or documents as PDF or JPG to other apps.
But that's a good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It would be pretty great to have Genius Scan as an Intent option. I will write you Mail with details of my Idea.

Comment: yes, thats why i did, didnt it work? Btw did you get my mail?

Comment: @guillaume-tgl is you app still not able to handle intents? I haven't seen any information about this on the app homepage...

Comment: No, still not. But I will think about it again.